# Does Hibernate has a feature of composite persistense unit?

Tags: hibernate, eclipselink, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

Does Hibernate has a feature of 'composite persistense unit ' like in EclipseLink. If no , then can we do cross schema mapping by some way in hibernate?

Comment: How does composite persistence unit" work?